# ATtiny13 at 16MHz? Why not?

Tags: clock, source

How exactly are you supposed to run the ATtiny13 at 16MHz or higher if you really have to?

What is the method and what external circuitry do you need to add?

Is it altogether more hassle than using an ATtiny25/85?

Answer (score 4):

**It’s all in the datasheets!**

The ATtiny13 can be driven by an external clock signal (by programming CKSEL with 00) but it does not have its own crystal oscillator.

You would need external circuitry (crystal, inverter + some capacitors and resistors) to generate the clock signal and drive the CLKI input (pin 2). You would not be able to use that pin for other purposes.

The ATtiny25 and 85 have the ability to directly connect a crystal (plus some capacitors) and drive it directly, BUT it needs two pins (2 and 3) on the chip, which is a lot for an 8-pin device.

So you need to define what you mean by “Hassle”, if you really need the performance and can live with the downsides.

Comment: Umm, here's what I've been up to, I'm trying to put together a rainbow neopixel (ws2812 ring) project in a 2.5 by 2.5 inch light diffuser and I only need one pin, I'm not good at coding so I used the led strip effects generator website and got some code, it worked with atmega328, atmega8, attiny2313 and attiny85 but not with the attiny13, the attiny13/85 are good fit for the diffuser but the 85 feels like an overkill so here I am..